# Do I need telnet access to hit API over VPN?

Tags: api, telnet, vpn

I need answer to one very basic question.

Is it necessary to have telnet access to hit an API while systems are connected over VPN? For example, if my system exposed an API for other systems to hit and they are connected in VPN using IPsec, does a third party system needs telnet access to my server for using that API? The API uses soap protocol for receiving request and sending response.

(I did not find out the solution using google. The question is so naive that I had to assume everyone must already know the answer and does not bother to discuss it in web. Sorry for bothering with this simple question)

Comment: I guess it won't be very helpful if I say that you don't **need** telnet to do that. You should rather rewrite the question as "How can I use an API with the following configuration and explain exactly the setup."

Comment: Hello Lacroix, thanks for your comment. Problem is I am not the developer for this purpose, I have exposed the API to a third party and their developer is trying to telnet to my server. Before banning him from my network, I am trying to figure out if there is any logic for doing so.

Comment: The answer to your question really depends on how the API is exposed, and also on what protocol port. If by "telnet" you mean your consumer is trying to connect on port 23 (the standard telnet port), and that's *not* where you expose your API, then you have a valid question to ask them. Otherwise, I'd need some more detail to understand the situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark, the API is exposed on 5555 port. This third party has been granted access in firewall and server for accessing that port. The API is XML over HTTP and using SOAP. While they are trying to telnet, they are getting a connection timed out response. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange. Accessing an http endpoint for anything else than dev using telnet doesn't really make much sense to me. If someone is using telnet to fetch informations from a server in an application. Something is already really wrong. If telnet is timing out while doing http requests. It's not really your fault and you shouldn't have to worry about edge cases like this.

If the dev is using telnet to **discover** security issues. This is a different issue and you could probably log anything that come from this particular client. If you gave hime some credentials, it should be easy to find who is doing which request. (I believe you might be already doing this).

You should probably ask the dev "why are you using telnet?". If for whatever reason the dev though he could send a plain SOAP request to your server using telnet without sending HTTP headers and so on.... then yes the connection is likely to timeout because the server isn't going to handle the request.

In my twisted mind, I can imagine some kind of legacy application calling scripts that open telnet sessions to parse some data and return the "parsed" data to the patched legacy project that doesn't handle http/tcp. I'd have in mind some sort of old Cobol application. Much more easier to do system call than to rewrite the whole thing to support APIs.

If for whatever reason, the client claims that telnet is needed for whatever reason. You can tell him back that telnet shouldn't be considered secure. Your api can be accessed using https. As far as I remember telnet doesn't encrypt anything unless you send encrypted data. If your client was able to hack a solution using telnet, I'm pretty sure they can hack a different solution wich use an actual http client.